# Difference between "Expiation" and "Atonement"

Tags: vocabulary

Can anybody explain the difference in meaning between 'expiation' and 'atonement'? Thanks.

Comment: ***Atonement, Expiation, Propitiation:***

http://www.spirithome.com/atonement.html

Comment: I am aware of that website, but I honestly couldn't make much sense out of it.

Comment: @Josh61 Why that tag?? They are all bad questions.

Comment: This would be better on [christianity.se], but, you'd have to specify whose definitions you want.

Comment: @GraziaCerulli Surely you should consider in such cases the mother of all synonym dictionaries:-) https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA312&dq=expiation+atonement+merriam+webster+synonym+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bVo-Vb-jLsKoyASK8YDYDg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=expiation%20atonement%20merriam%20webster%20synonym%20dictionary&f=true Do you see the page?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. The difference is a very subtle one indeed, at least to a foreign ear.

Comment: No, not 'the difference'. To the man in the street, the words are probably exactly synonymous (if he understands them at all). And modern dictionaries say that each has a spread of meanings, largely overlapping. The article in Marius's reference should be taken as one view, admittedly eloquent and reasoned and held by some schools, but not Gospel. The M-W Synonym Dictionary gives an answer from certain Christian schools (ie is in a distinct sub-register), not more everyday usage. It is also over 30 years old.

Comment: @ curiousdannii[2] I'm going to use _that_ one ('you'd have to specify whose definitions you want'). How often people want an answer that fits in with their preferences / opinions rather than a balanced one. I'm sure I've framed a question or two in a loaded way myself.

Answer (score 2):

"Atonement" is to attain forgiveness for some sin or transgression, e.g. "I atoned for betraying my friend". It is something that *you* do.

"Expiation" means to clear away the record, to make it as if it never existed. It is not something you can do - you cannot expiate your own sins.

It is very similar to the difference between *pardon* and *absolve* - atonement is like being pardoned, expiation is like being absolved.

When a crime has been expiated, everyone pretends it didn't happen. When it has been atoned for, everyone says "yes he did that, but he made up for it so we forgive him".

Comment: This may be so according to the way the words are sometimes used , but according to Collins say, the words are synonyms: **atonement** n 
1. satisfaction, reparation, or expiation given for an injury or wrong // We are looking for answers supported by authoritative references on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My understanding was that the U in ELU stands for USAGE, so I just put the way it is usually used. Anyone can google a definition, so I assumed OP was looking for more than "dictionary says X". Btw, OED & google have different definitions; Maybe look at them as well?

Comment: 'Usually used'? Dictionaries collect large samples of data and report on how terms are used across populations.  Anyone can say _how they feel the terms are usually used_. They're saying they know better than the professionals analysing broad trends in English usage. // I can only access [ODO (= 'Google')](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/atonement), not OED: **atonement**: 1The action of making amends for a wrong or injury; 1.1(In religious contexts) reparation or expiation for sin //
**expiation**: The act of making amends or reparation for guilt or wrongdoing; atonement

Comment: If you wish to use more precise definitions, you are of course free to do so. This is often done in legal, medical, religious, business, computing ... domains. But then it is only fair and sensible to define (narrow) your terms before you use them. ELU deals with general English; OP's question is framed in general terms (and in fact has been closed because of lack of focus / research). If an overview of more-or-less subject-specific usages is required, the relevant domain should be addressed (eg  'Christianity' as curiousdannii mentions.

Comment: He wisely adds: _But  you'd have to specify **whose** definitions you want._

Comment: Thanks for everybody's input. I was not aware of the ELL website, I'll post my question there. I hope that'll suffice to atone for my off-topic query.